# Specify a style sheet in Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have Bootstrap gem install on my app however I want to include a special style sheet for my login page. How would I include this style sheet without making the stylesheet global for all views (This is what is happening to me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) In the controller method that renders your login page, add the following line at the end of the method:

```
render :layout => false
```

That code will prevent the `application.html.erb` layout from being applied to the login page, assuming you want a 100% custom layout and stylesheet. If you're happy with the global layout being applied (the structure of the page, including any header or footer partials, etc.), then ignore this step.

2) In your `login.html.erb` (or whatever file contains your view), you'll need the following line, to point at your specific css file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'foo', media: 'print, screen' %>
```

where `foo` points to a `foo.css` file contained in your `app/assets/stylesheets` directory. You can skip the `media` bit if you don't want to differentiate between stylesheet media versions, but you may run into an issue with an unstyled view if the user ever tries to print the page, or if you're using a responsive layout.

3) Before that stylesheet link tag will work, you'll have to tell Rails to precompile it. In `your_app/config/initializers/assets.rb`, add the following line:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( foo.css )
```

4) Restart your Rails application.

5) Create and write your `foo.css` file.

You should see your view specific css being applied. Also... I herd u liek mudkipz.

Comment: It seems that I don't have `assets.rb` in my `initilizers` dir. Am I missing something or can I just add the file?

Comment: Look in config/initializers/assets.rb

Comment: Found it! Awesome, seems to be working! What about JS? Nothing special I have todo to call scripts apart from bootstrap?

Comment: If you have script code in your app/assets/scripts directory, you can call it in your app -- nothing special. Also, please post new questions separately -- there's no guarantee that I'll see comments you post here in the future.